# Aplicar estilos a un Componente dinamico en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estimados buenas tardes soy nuevo en React y me gustaria saber si hay una manera de aplicar estilos a la prop.testimonio ya que esos datos estan dentro de un objeto. En si lo que deberia lograr seria aplicarle negritas al: "**freeCodeCamp cambió mi vida**" del primer componente, "**freeCodeCamp fue la puerta de entrada a mi carrera**" del segundo componente y "**freeCodeCamp me dio las habilidades**" del tercer componente. Lo que se me ocurre es hacer algun filter con un replace, ´pero no se si seria la manera apropiada de aplicarlo o hay alguna manera mas sencilla??

Muchas gracias!!

App.js

```
function App() {

  const users = [
    {
      nombre:'Shawn Wang',
      pais:'Singapur',
      imagen:'Shawn',
      cargo:'Ingeniero de software',
      empresa:'Amazon',
            testimonio:'Da miedo cambiar de carrera. Solo gané la confianza de que podía programar trabajando en los cientos de horas de lecciones gratuitas en freeCodeCamp. En un año tenía un trabajo de seis cifras como ingeniero de software. freeCodeCamp cambió mi vida'        
    },
    {
      nombre:'Sara Chima',
      pais:'Nigeria',
      imagen:'Sarah',
      cargo:'Ingeniero de software',
      empresa:'ChatDesk',
      testimonio:'freeCodeCamp fue la puerta de entrada a mi carrera como desarrollador de software. El plan de estudios bien estructurado llevó mi conocimiento de codificación de un nivel de principiante total a un nivel muy seguro. Era todo lo que necesitaba para conseguir mi primer trabajo de desarrollador en una empresa increíble' 
    },
    {
      nombre:'Emma Bostian',
      pais:'Suecia',
      imagen:'Emma',
      cargo:'Ingeniero de software',
      empresa:'Spotify',
      testimonio:'Siempre me ha costado aprender JavaScript. Tomé muchos cursos, pero el curso de freeCodeCamp fue el que se quedó. Estudiar JavaScript, así como estructuras de datos y algoritmos en freeCodeCamp me dio las habilidades y la confianza que necesitaba para conseguir el trabajo de mis sueños como un ingeniero de software en Spotify'
    }
  ];


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='contenedor-principal'>
        <h1>Esto es lo que dicen nuestros alumnos sobre freeCodeCamp:</h1> 

        {
         users.map((user, index)=> {     

          return (<Testimonio
                    key={index}
                    nombre={user.nombre}
                    pais={user.pais}
                    imagen={user.imagen}
                    cargo={user.cargo}
                    empresa={user.empresa}
                    testimonio={user.testimonio}    
                  />)
              })
        }
     
      </div>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Testimonios.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../hojas-de-estilo/Testimonio.css'

function Testimonio(props) {

  return (
    <div className='contenedor-testimonio'>
      <img 
          className='imagen-testimonio' 
          src={require(`../imagenes/testimonio-${props.imagen}.png`)} 
          alt={`Foto de ${props.imagen}`} />
      <div className='contenedor-texto-testimonio'>
        <p className='nombre-testimonio'>
          <strong>{props.nombre}</strong> en {props.pais}
        </p>
        <p className='cargo-testimonio'>
          {props.cargo} en <strong>{props.empresa}</strong>
        </p>
        <p className='texto-testimonio'>"{props.testimonio}."</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Testimonio;
```

Comment: y el componente Testimonio que hace?

Comment: El componente testimonio solo se muestra no realiza nada

Comment: si quieres estilizar las props que mandas a testimonio debes mostrarnos el componente para ver como lo has estructurado

Comment: y en la hoja de estilos no tienes .texto-testimonio{font-weight: bold;}?                      Podrias intentar tambien: <p className='texto-testimonio' style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>"{props.testimonio}."</p>

Comment: Hernan García si aplicó el font weight bold a texto.testimonio lo estaría aplicando a todo el texto de la prop.testimonio la idea sería aplicarlo solo a determinados textos dentro de la prop

Comment: ah! ok, ahora entiendo, solo parte del texto. Pregunta:el arreglo users lo tomas dinamicamente o lo creas arbitrariamente. El tema es cual es el criterio que usas para determinar cual sera el texto que deba ir en bold

Comment: si tu armas manualmente cada objeto seria muy facil, rodeas la frase que quieres con una etiqueta bold y listo

Comment: Claro yo lo pensé manualmente de la misma manera pero desde que lo aplique tomando los datos del objeto users y luego lo itero con el map, me di cuenta que se me iba a complicar con la prop.testimonios ya que tiene parte del texto en bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues si puedes modificar el arreglo de objetos a gusto se puede poner la etiqueta `<b></b>` rodeando al texto que quieras. Pero al tratarse de react no te permite en primera instancia inyectar html puro. Pero usando la propiedad dangerouslySetInnerHTML en la etiqueta que quieres inyectar HTML si es posible,, esta es la manera:

```
function Pruebas() {
  const users = [
    {
      nombre: "Shawn Wang",
      pais: "Singapur",
      imagen: "Shawn",
      cargo: "Ingeniero de software",
      empresa: "Amazon",
      testimonio:
        "Da miedo cambiar de carrera. Solo gané la confianza de que podía programar trabajando en los cientos de horas de lecciones gratuitas en freeCodeCamp. En un año tenía un trabajo de seis cifras como ingeniero de software. <b>freeCodeCamp cambió mi vida</b>",
    },
    {
      nombre: "Sara Chima",
      pais: "Nigeria",
      imagen: "Sarah",
      cargo: "Ingeniero de software",
      empresa: "ChatDesk",
      testimonio:
        "<b>freeCodeCamp fue la puerta de entrada a mi carrera</b> como desarrollador de software. El plan de estudios bien estructurado llevó mi conocimiento de codificación de un nivel de principiante total a un nivel muy seguro. Era todo lo que necesitaba para conseguir mi primer trabajo de desarrollador en una empresa increíble",
    },
    {
      nombre: "Emma Bostian",
      pais: "Suecia",
      imagen: "Emma",
      cargo: "Ingeniero de software",
      empresa: "Spotify",
      testimonio:
        "Siempre me ha costado aprender JavaScript. Tomé muchos cursos, pero el curso de freeCodeCamp fue el que se quedó. Estudiar JavaScript, así como estructuras de datos y algoritmos en <b>freeCodeCamp me dio las habilidades</b> y la confianza que necesitaba para conseguir el trabajo de mis sueños como un ingeniero de software en Spotify",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="contenedor-principal">
        <h1>Esto es lo que dicen nuestros alumnos sobre freeCodeCamp:</h1>

        {users.map((user, index) => {
          return (
            <Testimonio
              key={index}
              nombre={user.nombre}
              pais={user.pais}
              imagen={user.imagen}
              cargo={user.cargo}
              empresa={user.empresa}
              testimonio={user.testimonio}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pruebas;

function Testimonio(props) {
  return (
    <div className="contenedor-testimonio">
      <img
        className="imagen-testimonio"
        src={require(`../imagenes/testimonio-${props.imagen}.png`)}
        alt={`Foto de ${props.imagen}`}
      />
      <div className="contenedor-texto-testimonio">
        <p className="nombre-testimonio">
          <strong>{props.nombre}</strong> en {props.pais}
        </p>
        <p className="cargo-testimonio">
          {props.cargo} en <strong>{props.empresa}</strong>
        </p>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.testimonio }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Espero te sirva...

Comment: Genial muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para inyectar una etiqueta HTML dentro del texto del prop puedes hacer esto (coloco solo la parte relevante):

```
<Testimonio

testimonio = {[<strong>freeCodeCamp</strong>, ' fue la puerta... etc.']}

      />
```

No te recomiendo usar *dangerouslySetInnerHTML* porque puede abrirte a un ataque de cross-site scripting (XSS) si no estás sanitizando los valores de las propiedades